# Python re-export another script with the same name

Tags: python

I am new to python. My searches did not give the results I am after.

I have a simple python script in `folder_base/settings.py`.

My other script in `folder_next/settings.py` would like to behave as `folder_base/settings.py`. One way is to use symbolic links but I avoid this method. I want any function called from `folder_next/settings.py`, they call the one in the base folder and return the same value.

I was even trying methods such as

```
from ..folder_base/settings.py import func1 as _func1

def func1():
    return _func1()
```

which did not work for me. Any solution is appreciated but a solution that automatically forward the entire script is even better.

P.S. The linked question does not solve my problem. Adding another path just creates a name collision.

Can some one please remove the irrelevant duplication link?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: Can you give a better picture of your file hierarchy? It's possible that your relative imports aren't working here because the parent directory of both `folder_base` and `folder_next` doesn't have a `__init__.py` file.

Comment: @James it does not solve the name collision.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy, Just two folder and a few independent settings file in each. `C++` calls them, read them and behaves as configured.

Comment: @twist what is the main entry point into your project? does your project contain any other modules, folders, or files? when you run your project is `folder_next/settings.py` the first file you run? more info on how you run your project is helpful to provide an answer.

Comment: I have an idea to accomplish what you want to do but it requires adding another script in the parent folder above `folder_next` and `folder_base`, if you put `from folder_next import settings` in the parent folder script, then you can call `from folder_base.settings import func1` in `folder_next/settings.py`.